# Is there a reverse way to find number of people with given 0.5 probability that two people will have same birthday but no using mathematical formula?

Tags: python-2.7, random, probability, reverse, birthday-paradox

I'm doing birthday paradox, and want to know how many people can meet 0.5 probability that two people have same birthday by using python.

I have tried no using mathematical formula to find probability with given the number of people by using random and randint in python

```
import random
def random_birthdays():
    bdays = []
    bdays = [random.randint(1, 365) for i in range(23)]
    bdays.sort()
    for x in range(len(bdays)):
        while x < len(bdays)-1:
            print x
            if bdays[x] == bdays[x+1]:
                #print(bdays[x])
                return True
            x+=1
        return False
count  = sum(random_birthdays() for _ in range(1000))
print('In a sample of 1000 classes each with 23 pupils, there were', count, 'classes with individuals with the same birthday')
```

I expect some hints or codes that can help me through this.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Can you try to be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem with your code you check only consecutive birthday equality. Better check it using sets

Along the line

```
import random

def sim(n):
    """simulate birthdays for n people"""
    a = set([random.randint(1, 365) for _ in range(n)])
    if len(a) == n:
        return False
    return True

print(sim(23))
print(sim(23))
print(sim(23))
print(sim(23))
print(sim(23))
```

Function above will return true if there are same day birthday for `n` people, false otherwise.

Call it 1000000 times for n = 20, 21, ...., 25 and count how many Trues vs Falses are there

Running code

```
nt = 0
nf = 0
n = 23
for k in range(0, 1000000):
    if sim(n):
        nt += 1
    else:
        nf += 1

print((nt, nf))
```

for n = 23 and n = 22 produced

```
(506245, 493755)
(475290, 524710)
```