# Birthday Paradox in Python with monte carlo method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, montecarlo, birthday-paradox

Trying to find the smallest # of people needed to "enter" a room to have a probability of at least 50% for two people sharing the same birthday, using the monte carlo method (the well known solution is 23 people, but I cant seem to find my errors in logic, or implementation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reverse way to find number of people with given 0.5 probability that two people will have same birthday but no using mathematical formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814174/is-there-a-reverse-way-to-find-number-of-people-with-given-0-5-probability-that)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in expressing how you look for an existing date:

```
if date in [dates]:
```

Let's just take the case where you've already found dates 3 and 15, and you just drew another 15 birthday.  This check statement evaluates as

```
if 15 in [ [3, 15] ]:
```

This is `False`!  The expression on the right has *one* element, a list.  There is no way that an integer (`15`) and a list (`[3, 15]`) can be equal, so the check will always fail.  Instead, use the `in` check as seen in your tutorials:

```
if date in dates:
```

Output:

```
double birthday 1
double birthday 2
double birthday 3
double birthday 4
double birthday 5
double birthday 6
double birthday 7
double birthday 8
double birthday 9
double birthday 10
double birthday 11
double birthday 12
double birthday 13
13.0
```

Yes, you have a couple more errors in your code.  You printed a counter instead of the duplicates date, and you reset `counter` every time through the loop, so your final proportion is always dividing by `1`.

Once you fix those, the output will look like

```
double birthday 204
double birthday 40
double birthday 268
double birthday 260
double birthday 188
double birthday 136
double birthday 324
0.07
```

Finally, your problem description says that you exit the loop when you find a duplicate.  As the above output shows, this is *not* what you're doing.  You will need a `break` statement for that.